# Command to change user's nickname Discord

Tags: c#, discord

I have been trying to create a command via a discord bot in C# that allows people to change another user's nickname and then sends a PM to the admins reporting that the user's nickname has changed and who was responsible for changing the name. Everything is working except for the actual nickname changing. The code I have tried to use to accomplish this is

```
    userBeingChanged.Nickname = newName;
```

But it says that I can't do this because it is read only. Does anyone know of an alternative way to change a user's nickname?

Edit: I am only trying to change the nickname not Username and the bot in question does have Administrator permissions. The above code does not compile and I was asking if there was an alternative way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it actually possible to change another persons nickname? I would think this would be a major oversight.

Comment: Once you complete your code, I would love it if you change my wife's nickname, I will send you the new one privately.

Comment: make another get;set; property? if this one is must read only.

Comment: How would you go about doing that with the Discord API?

Comment: @l'L'l it's definitely possible for a bot to change a users _nickname_ on the same server as the bot, as long as the bot has the manage nicknames or admin permission.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely has to look like this.

```
await userBeingChanged.Edit(nickname: newName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Not sure which version you're using, but here is an example.

```
cmd.CreateCommand("setnick")
            .Description("Changes, or sets, the nickname of the specified user.")
            .Parameter("user")
            .Parameter("newname", ParameterType.Unparsed)
            .Do(async (e) =>
        {
            var user = e.Channel.FindUsers(e.GetArg("user")).FirstOrDefault();
            string newname = e.GetArg("newname");
            await user.Edit(nickname: newname).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
```

I wrote this one for you, but I hope you understand how this works, should you make another command with a similar function.

We're adding two parameters to the command, `user` and `newname`. The reason `newname` is unparsed, while `user` isn't, is because in `user` you can mention the user, or write it in plain text. However, `user` can't contain spaces, so your best option would be to mention the user if it contains spaces, or copy-paste his current display name. `newname` is unparsed, because it *can* contain spaces.

You can't have two unparsed parameters in one command, as only the first one will be given a value no matter the length of your message, it will be unreachable.

**Remember, the user needs to be online if you are to change his nickname.**

I'll give you an example on how `e.GetArg()` works. Writing a simple command to make the bot say whatever you tell it to.

```
cmd.CreateCommand("say")
            .Parameter("msg", ParameterType.Unparsed)
            .Do(async (e) =>
        {
            string message = e.GetArg("msg");
            await e.Channel.SendMessage(message);
        });
```

Usage: `!say Hello, this works.`, would make the bot say *Hello, this works.*. And naturally, the parameter has to be unparsed, because the message contains spaces. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The bot should need the "Manage Nickname" permission or the "Administrator" permission to change the nickname of someone on the server.

Remember, this only allows you to change the *nickname* of the person on the server, not their *global* discord name.

The issue might be originating there, as the bot's trying to do something it's not allowed to do.

Comment: It's not an issue with permissions, the above code does not compile since the nickname property is read only and I don't know if there is another set name property. The bot in question has administrator permissions on the server I am using it in.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    [Command("nick")]
    [Description("Change a user's nickname")]
    public async Task NicknameSet(CommandContext ctx, [Description("Nickname to change")] DiscordMember user, [Description("New name")] string nickname)
    {
        DiscordMember discordMember = user;
        var oldNick = discordMember.Nickname;
        await ctx.TriggerTypingAsync();
        try
        {
            await discordMember.ModifyAsync(x => x.Nickname = nickname);
            var newNick = discordMember.Nickname;
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{ctx.Member.Username} changed {oldNick}'s nickname to: {newNick}.").ConfigureAwait(false);
            newNick = "";

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync
                ($"An error occured: {e}").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```